# Android ListView - Unclickable Checkbox

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I am hoping someone has seen this problem before. I have a listview where all the elements have a checkbox. This all works well, except that there is one checkbox that is unselectable (can't check and uncheck it). It isn't the first item in the list, and the problem isn't there on all devices. Works fine on a Samsung S3, but has a problem on the Nexus 6P.

After some investigating I turned on 'Show layout bounds' in the developer options. This is where I saw something very interesting, the unclickable element didn't draw any bounds. In the example below the checkbox for 'Bar Tunes' is unselectable.

[image: Layout Bounds]

Does anyone have an idea why this might be happening. Here is the layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_10sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/listRow"
    android:background="@color/GreyLight">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="@dimen/list_40sp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/list_40sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_5sp"
            android:checked="true"
            android:id="@+id/selectedCheckbox"
            android:button="@drawable/button_checkbox_image"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/connectedIcon"
            android:src="@drawable/tick_raw"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/list_20sp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/list_20sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_20sp"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/textBackground">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_10sp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/list_5sp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/list_5sp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/searchList"
            android:background="@drawable/button_list_item"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.hdms.manager.Drawable.NightlifeTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="List Name"
                android:textSize="@dimen/list_text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/listName"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="middle"/>

            <com.hdms.manager.Drawable.NightlifeTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/playlist_neg_2sp"
                android:text="(User Friendly Name)"
                android:textSize="@dimen/playlist_text_size"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:id="@+id/friendlyName" />

            <com.hdms.manager.Drawable.NightlifeTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="List Description"
                android:textSize="@dimen/list_text_size_smaller"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:id="@+id/listDescription" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/playlist_40sp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/playlist_40sp"
            android:padding="@dimen/account_2sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/account_5sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:id="@+id/crowdDJButton"
            android:src="@drawable/crowddj_icon"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background_green"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/playlist_40sp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/playlist_40sp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_nm"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/account_5sp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:tint="@color/White"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background_green"
            android:padding="@dimen/account_2sp"
            android:id="@+id/musicSystemButton"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/playlist_20sp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/playlist_20sp"
            android:padding="@dimen/playlist_2sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/player_5sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/crowdDJSearchable"
            android:background="@color/StormGreen"
            android:src="@drawable/crowddj_icon"/>

        <com.hdms.manager.Drawable.NightlifeTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="@dimen/list_text_size_smaller"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/list_45sp"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/list_25sp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:id="@+id/songCount"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/border_rounded_darkgrey"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot"
            android:src="@drawable/dot_dot_dot"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/account_10sp"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/list_20sp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/list_20sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_1sp"
        android:background="@drawable/verticalline"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any suggestions for how to fix or track down this problem? Thanks

Here is some adaptor code, as it goes over the text limit for a post.

```
    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int position, boolean isLastChild, View aView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        final Object item = getChild(groupPosition, position);
        switch (mMode)
        {
            case Spotify:
                if (aView == null || aView.getId() != R.id.spotifyRow)
                    aView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_spotify_item, null);

                aView.setTag("" + position);
                setupSpotifyLists(aView, item);
                break;
            case SelectionSets:
                if (aView == null || aView.getId() != R.id.selection)
                    aView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.selection_item, null);

                setupSelectionSets(aView, (HDMSLiveSession.SelectionSet) item);
                break;
            case SelectionSet:
                if (aView == null || aView.getId() != R.id.selection)
                    aView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.selection_item, null);

                setupSelectionSet(aView, (String) item);
                break;
            default:
                HDMSLiveSession.SystemLists data = HDMSLiveSession.getInstance().getMLData((String) item);

                if (data != null || item.equals(gSpotifyList))
                {
                    if (aView == null || aView.getId() != R.id.listRow)
                        aView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

                    setupList(data, aView, (String) item);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (aView == null || aView.getId() != R.id.list_sub)
                        aView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.lists_subheading, null);

                    setupSubHeading((String) item, aView);
                }
                break;
        }

        return aView;
    }

        private void setupList(final HDMSLiveSession.SystemLists aData, View aView, final String aList)
    {
        LinearLayout textBackground = (LinearLayout)aView.findViewById(R.id.textBackground);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
            textBackground.setBackground(aView.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.list_background));
        else
            textBackground.setBackgroundDrawable(aView.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.list_background));

        LinearLayout listSearch = (LinearLayout)aView.findViewById(R.id.searchList);
        listSearch.setClickable(true);
        final boolean ambient = aData != null && (aData.mGroup.equals("Ambient") || aData.mGroup.equals("User Ambient"));
        final boolean karaoke = aData != null && (aData.mGroup.toUpperCase().equals("KARAOKE") || aList.contains("KARAOKE"));
        listSearch.setOnClickListener(new NightlifeOnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View aView)
            {
                super.onClick(aView);

                if (mListener != null)
                    mListener.onListSearch(aList, ambient, karaoke, aData);
            }
        });

        // the user friendly name (or id if no friendly name is available)
        TextView name = (TextView)aView.findViewById(R.id.listName);
        String count = aData == null && MusicPreview.getInstance().isLoggedIn() ? (MusicPreview.getInstance().getLinkedCount() >= 0 ? " - " + MusicPreview.getInstance().getLinkedCount() : " - N/A") : "";
        SpannableString content = new SpannableString(aList + count);
        content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, content.length(), 0);
        if (aData == null)
            name.setText(content);
        else if(aData.mUserName != null && !aData.mUserName.isEmpty())
            name.setText(aData.mUserName);
        else
            name.setText(aList);

        // description of the list
        TextView description = (TextView)aView.findViewById(R.id.listDescription);
        String descriptionText = aData != null ? aData.mDescription :
                (MusicPreview.getInstance().isLoggedIn() && MusicPreview.getInstance().getLinkedTitle() != null && !MusicPreview.getInstance().getLinkedTitle().isEmpty() ?
                        MusicPreview.getInstance().getLinkedTitle() : "No Selected Spotify List.");
        description.setText(descriptionText);

        // id if friendly name is available)
        TextView userName = (TextView)aView.findViewById(R.id.friendlyName);
        boolean spotify = aData != null && aData.mGroup.toUpperCase().equals("SPOTIFY");
        if (aData != null && aData.mUserName != null && !aData.mUserName.isEmpty() && !spotify)
        {
            userName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            userName.setText("( " + aList + " )");
        }
        else
            userName.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        ImageView tick = (ImageView)aView.findViewById(R.id.connectedIcon);
        boolean listLoaded;
        if (ambient)
        {
            listLoaded = HDMSLiveSession.getInstance().isAmbientListLoaded(aList);
        }
        else
        {
            listLoaded = HDMSLiveSession.getInstance().isSelectionsOnly() ? HDMSLiveSession.getInstance().isSelectionList(aList) : HDMSLiveSession.getInstance().isListLoaded(aList);
        }

        ImageView dot = (ImageView)aView.findViewById(R.id.dot);
        if (aData == null)
        {
            tick.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            dot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            dot.setColorFilter(aView.getResources().getColor(R.color.Black));
            dot.setClickable(true);
            dot.setOnClickListener(new NightlifeOnClickListener()
            {
                @Override public void onClick(View aView)
                {
                    super.onClick(aView);

                    if (mListener != null)
                        mListener.onSelectSpotifyList();
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            dot.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tick.setVisibility(listLoaded ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            tick.setImageResource(R.drawable.tick_raw);
            tick.setColorFilter(aView.getResources().getColor(R.color.StormGreen));
        }

        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)aView.findViewById(R.id.selectedCheckbox);
        checkBox.setEnabled(mEnableCheckBoxes && isSelectable(aData, aList) && !isInSelectionSet(aList));
        Log.e("List", aList + " " + checkBox.isEnabled());
        mIgnore = true;
        if (mListener != null)
            checkBox.setChecked(mListener.isSelected(aList));
        else
            checkBox.setChecked(false);

        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton aCompoundButton, boolean aChecked)
            {
                Log.e("List", aList + " onCheckedChanged: " + aChecked);
                if (mListener != null && !mIgnore)
                    mListener.onListSelected(aList, aData, aChecked);
            }
        });
        mIgnore = false;

        if (!mShowLoadingCheckbox)
        {
            tick.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            dot.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        TextView songCount = (TextView)aView.findViewById(R.id.songCount);
        if (aData != null)
            songCount.setText(String.valueOf(aData.mSongCount));
        songCount.setVisibility(aData != null ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

        if (HDMSLiveSession.getInstance().isSelectionsOnly())
        {
            if (listLoaded)
                songCount.setTextColor(songCount.getResources().getColor(R.color.White));
            else
                songCount.setTextColor(songCount.getResources().getColor(R.color.Grey));
        }
        else
            songCount.setTextColor(songCount.getResources().getColor(R.color.White));

        // crowdDJ Icon
        boolean discovery = aData != null && HDMSLiveSession.getInstance().isDiscoveryList(aData.mName);

        View searchable = aView.findViewById(R.id.crowdDJSearchable);
        searchable.setVisibility(/*spotify && */discovery ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }

    private boolean isSelectable(HDMSLiveSession.SystemLists aData, String aList)
    {
        boolean isSpotifyList = aData == null;
        boolean selectable = isSpotifyList && MusicPreview.getInstance().isLoggedIn();

        if (!isSpotifyList)
        {
            boolean useList = aData.mGroup.toUpperCase().equals("UNKNOWN");
            boolean negative = aData.mGroup.toLowerCase().equals("negative");
            boolean deleted = aList.toUpperCase().equals("DELETED") || aList.toUpperCase().equals("TAGGED") || aList.toUpperCase().equals("HIDDEN");
            boolean ambient = aData.mGroup.toLowerCase().equals("ambient") || aData.mGroup.toLowerCase().equals("user ambient");
            boolean karaoke = aData.mGroup.toUpperCase().equals("KARAOKE");
            selectable |= !(!aData.mLoadable && !useList || negative || deleted) && !karaoke;
        }

        return selectable;
    }

    private boolean isInSelectionSet(String aList)
    {
        return HDMSLiveSession.getInstance().getVersionID() > 3.909 && HDMSLiveSession.getInstance().isSelectionsOnly() && !HDMSLiveSession.getInstance().isSelectionList(aList);
    }
```

These are the relevant functions. The list view is an ExpandableListView, if that helps.

This problem only seems to occur on Android 7.0 and later. I have confirmed this on Android 8 as well.

Comment: Please also paste your adapter codes.

Comment: Looks like the selected item using a different layout,  is selection_item?

Comment: The code is always going into the default: case and always has data. I have added an onTouch Listener, the code always gets called. The onCheckedChanged Listener is never getting called.

Comment: Even setting the checkbox to checked / unchecked in the onTouch listener doesn't work.

Comment: Is there a line of code in your `Adapter` return `new View(Context)` (or something like this) ? I have the same problem and I created an issue for Android team here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65104968

Comment: No, all views are created using the layout inflater.

Comment: About setting the checkbox to checked/unchecked, I looked at the  `setupList()` method. I saw that you setup checked/unchecked listener(`checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener`) after calling `checkBox.setChecked()` method. I think you should swap them to retrieve the callback when using `checkBox.setChecked()` method

Comment: No, the code works fine for all other check boxes except the on in the image without any clip bounds showing. I suspect we have the same bug in Android, I have added my observations to your issue with google.

Comment: @bradJ: Yeah! If you reproduce your problem you should leave a comment on this issue so that Google can fix it easily. So you should look at your code carefully one again. Hope you fix the bug soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found a fix for this problem. The cell's position is set to 0,0.
I have overridden the dispatchTouchEvent of the ListView, the partial code is as below.

```
        case ACTION_UP:
            // HACK: This is a fix for Android setting some views position to 0,0
            if (mPassOnTouch)
            {
                View view = getChild(aMotionEvent);
                if (view != null && isBadView(view))
                {
                    int[] location = new int[2];
                    getLocationInWindow(location);

                    List<View> views = findClickableViews(view, new Vector<View>());
                    for (View subView: views)
                    {
                        int[] position = calculatePosition(subView, view, location);
                        if (isWithIn(subView, position, (int)aMotionEvent.getRawX(), (int)aMotionEvent.getRawY()))
                        {
                            subView.performClick();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
```

The code checks for the view under the motion events position. (All the data required to get the views position is available, but the functions getLocationInWindow or getLocationOnScreen are wrong). I then check to see if the views position is at 0,0. Then find all the subviews that are clickable, and adjust their positions manually.

The perform click was required, as the onTouchEvent requires a 'correct' location.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have some item that didn't use the `convertView` which the `ListView` give to you. And the next time you get this view and use it, it will be like this.
Advise use `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()` when you have different view implement.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, however if you look at the code closely you will find that my convertView is called aView and I check for both null and the wrong type. Cheers